# Returning Books JSON through dotnetbrowser

Tags: c#, json, dotnetbrowser

I am trying to return JSON string through `XMlHTTPRequest` response body. the problem is after the method create and instance of `AjaxResourceHandler` it will go ahead and execute the Get method before getting the required data which returns an empty string. What I want is to be able to return the response body as JSON string.
and one more thing; can web browser do the same thing; if so how?

```
using AjaxRequest.Models;
using DotNetBrowser;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace AjaxRequest.Controllers
{
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    
  
    private static List<string> ajaxUrls = new List<string>();
    private static List<string> sourceDat = new List<string>();
    private static Browser browser;

    public ValuesController()
    {
        browser = BrowserFactory.Create();
        browser.Context.NetworkService.ResourceHandler = new AjaxResourceHandler();
        browser.Context.NetworkService.NetworkDelegate = new AjaxNetworkDelegate();

        browser.LoadURL("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_examples.asp");
        //browser.Dispose();
    }


    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        //Init();
        return sourceDat;

    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        
        return "value";
        
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }

    //private  void Init()
    //{
       
    //}

    public class AjaxResourceHandler : ResourceHandler
    {
        public bool CanLoadResource(ResourceParams parameters)
        {
            if (parameters.ResourceType == ResourceType.XHR && parameters.URL.Contains("https://123movies.is/ajax/v2_get_sources"))
            {

                ajaxUrls.Add(parameters.URL);

            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class AjaxNetworkDelegate : DefaultNetworkDelegate
    {
        public override void OnDataReceived(DataReceivedParams parameters)
        {
            if (ajaxUrls.Contains(parameters.Url))
            {

                PrintResponseData(parameters.Data);

            }
           
        }
        public void PrintResponseData(byte[] data)
        {

            var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            
            BookSource _sources = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BookSource>(str);
            sourceDat.Add(_sources.ToString());
            browser.Dispose();
            //source.Add(_sources);

            //return source;
        }

    }
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a `ManualResetEvent` to block main thread until AJAX response is caught.
The sample code below demonstrates how to implement this approach:

```
using AjaxRequest.Models;
using DotNetBrowser;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace AjaxRequest.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {

        private static ManualResetEvent waitEvent;
        private static List<string> ajaxUrls = new List<string>();
        private static List<string> sourceDat = new List<string>();
        private static Browser browser;

        public ValuesController()
        {
            waitEvent = waitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            browser = BrowserFactory.Create();
            browser.Context.NetworkService.ResourceHandler = new AjaxResourceHandler();
            browser.Context.NetworkService.NetworkDelegate = new AjaxNetworkDelegate();

            browser.LoadURL("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_examples.asp");
            //browser.Dispose();
        }

        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            //Init();
            waitEvent.WaitOne();
            return sourceDat;

        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {

            return "value";

        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }

        //private  void Init()
        //{

        //}

        public class AjaxResourceHandler : ResourceHandler
        {
            public bool CanLoadResource(ResourceParams parameters)
            {
                if (parameters.ResourceType == ResourceType.XHR && parameters.URL.Contains("https://123movies.is/ajax/v2_get_sources"))
                {

                    ajaxUrls.Add(parameters.URL);

                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        public class AjaxNetworkDelegate : DefaultNetworkDelegate
        {
            public override void OnDataReceived(DataReceivedParams parameters)
            {
                if (ajaxUrls.Contains(parameters.Url))
                {

                    PrintResponseData(parameters.Data);

                }

            }
            public void PrintResponseData(byte[] data)
            {

                var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

                BookSource _sources = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BookSource>(str);
                sourceDat.Add(_sources.ToString());
                waitEvent.Set();
                browser.Dispose();
                //source.Add(_sources);

                //return source;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

As far as I know, there is no possibility to intercept AJAX responce directly in WebBrowser. There seems to be a workaround to intercept it through ObjectForScripting: [catch ajax response data in web browser control C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332043/catch-ajax-response-data-in-web-browser-control-c-sharp)

Comment: it works and thank you very much. I will look into ObjectForScripting